# Admin Tools config throws 404: page not found

Tags: django-admin-tools

I try to setup the basic configuration of admin tools and fail with the url dispatcher recognizing the include of admin_tools.urls:

```
#urls.py
...
import admin_tools.urls
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admintools/', include(admin_tools.urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

#settings.py
import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    ...
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'repmgr',)
```

I did run syncdb. I am sure that the regexp matches /admintools/, because it works when I include another app.

The detailed error response is:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admintools/
Using the URLconf defined in urlconf, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^__debug__/m/(.*)$
^__debug__/sql_select/$ [name='sql_select']
^__debug__/sql_explain/$ [name='sql_explain']
^__debug__/sql_profile/$ [name='sql_profile']
^__debug__/template_source/$ [name='template_source']
^admin/doc/
^admintools/ ^menu/
^admintools/ ^dashboard/
^sthrep/
The current URL, admintools/, didn't match any of these.
```

Comment: Please provide the full error.

Comment: In the meantime I realized, that the /admin/ URL (actually /sthrep/ in my case) does show the dashboard now. I am not sure which of my changes effected this.
Still I find it confusing to define a URL mapping that is no real mapping. In addition, the error message is not correct, because django complains about the URL-pattern, which is not the culprit, the problem must be with the include.

Answer (score 2):

**The error message is perfectly correct :**

Django tells that there is no URL pattern matching `^admintools/^`. **That is true**. This is because django-admin-tools does not create a different admin site, but rather extends the original admin site.

The `^admintools/` pattern is only created for its sub-patterns, that provide access to pages needed by admin-tools to work well (new pages added to the original admin, for example).

By the way, in [django-admin-tools documentation](http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#testing-your-new-shiny-admin-interface), at the end of the setup instructions, they say :

> *Congrats! At this point you should have a working installation of
> django-admin-tools. Now you can just login to your admin site and see
> what changed.*

I guess that by *your admin site* they mean the standard admin site.

So I think that the good way to access your admin interface and menus and dashboards is using the standard admin.